# Is it possible to test cordova application using Appium

Tags: android, ios, cordova, selenium-webdriver, appium

Is it really possible to test Cordova Application using Appium on Android or iOS.

I am trying the below code and getting exception.

```
    File appDir = new File("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Android");
    File app = new File(appDir, "App.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.3");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());



    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    String script="alert('hello');";

    JavascriptExecutor executor=driver;
    executor.executeAsyncScript(script);
```

The application is getting launched successfully on android but I get following exception on executing Script.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Added this comment on behalf of Winster Jose: I was getting a similar error and I could solve it. Please check this [Appium only shows NATIVE_APP context on a Cordova App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426385/appium-only-shows-native-app-context-on-a-cordova-app)